# I am trying to combine 6 columns into two, I cant use concatenate, Google Sheets is constantly updating the rows

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, max, google-query-language

So I am trying to combine 6 columns

| Number | Date | Number | Date | Number | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/12/21 | 2 | 2/20/21 | 3 | 3/5/21 |
| 2 | 2/12/21 | 3 | 2/27/21 | 4 | 4/1/21 |
| 3 | 1/15/20 | 4 | 1/20/21 | 1 | 3/30/21 |
| 4 | 1/4/21 | 1 | 2/25/21 | 2 | 4/2/21 |

So what I am trying to accomplish is that these rows would combine into two with the latest date being displayed:

| Number | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/30/21 |
| 2 | 4/2/21 |
| 3 | 3/5/21 |
| 4 | 4/1/21 |

To get the latest date, I have tried to use

```
=query('scba fill practise'!A:G,"select A, max(G) group by A")
```

To get all my numbers to constantly update, I've used

```
=UNIQUE({A3:A;C3:C;E3:E})
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
=QUERY({'scba fill practise'!A2:B4;'scba fill practise'!C2:D4;'scba fill practise'!E2:F4}, "SELECT Col1, MAX(Col2) GROUP BY Col1")
```

[image]